# The sum of $1^2+7^2+13^2+\cdots+n^2,$ where $ n =1 \mod6 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

Find the sum of this progression in the terms of $n$

$$1^2+7^2+13^2+\cdots+n^2,$$ where $ n =1 \mod6 $.

Are Bernoulli's numbers involved in this? Please help.

Comment: The Question has meant $$n\equiv1\pmod6$$ right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, we need $\displaystyle\sum_{r=0}^m(6r+1)^2$

which is
$$36\sum_{r=0}^mr^2+12\sum_{r=0}^mr+\sum_{r=0}^m1$$

$$=36\sum_{r=1}^mr^2+12\sum_{r=1}^mr+(m+1)$$

**References** :

[Proving the sum of the first $n$ natural numbers by induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292423/proving-the-sum-of-the-first-n-natural-numbers-by-induction)

[How to get to the formula for the sum of squares of first n numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183316/how-to-get-to-the-formula-for-the-sum-of-squares-of-first-n-numbers)

Answer (score 0):

After simplifications :

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n} (6*k+1)^2 = (n+1)\left(12n^2+12n+1\right)
$$

Shadock

Comment: Note that the usage of $n$ here is not the same as in the problem statement.

Comment: And why ? He write the sum with n^2 and if n=1 mod 6 so n=6k+1 with k in Z so i don't understand you :/

Comment: ...because I'm being silly. Woops.

Comment: He writes* Woops ^^