# Connection between "proof by induction" and "arbitrary element" arguments

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I'm guessing that this is more of a metalogic question; I am not very familiar with this area so I apologize if the terminology is lackluster.

As I advance through my math curriculum, I notice that proof by mathematical induction is becoming quite a common tool. Alternatively, I also see that the method of "arbitrary element" (not sure what the actual name is) is quite common. Only very rarely do I see examples where one can use **both** strategies to prove a proposition. For example, consider proving the statement that $\frac{n(n+1)}{2} = 1 + 2 + ... +n$... or, more formally:

$$f: \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$$

$$f(n) = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

$$g: \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$$

$$g(n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}i$$

$$\forall n \big(n \in \mathbb N \land n\geq 1 \implies f(n)=g(n)\big)$$

There is the traditional proof by induction (which is widely available)...but can be found on the website here: [Proving the sum of the first $n$ natural numbers by induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292423/proving-the-sum-of-the-first-n-natural-numbers-by-induction?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Then there is the method of "arbitrary element" which could be described as follows:

Choose an arbitrary element $n^*$.

Consider $g(n^*) = 1 + 2 + ... n^*$

Multiply this by $2$ and, for illustrative purposes, strategically arrange the sum as follows:

$2g(n^*)= \big (\color{blue}{1}+\color{green}{2}+...\color{red}{n^*} \big) + \big( \color{blue}{n^*}+\color{green}{n^*-1}+...+\color{red}{1} \big) = n^*(n^*+1)$

$g(n^*) = \frac{n^*(n^*+1)}{2}$

---

As demonstrated above, the proposition $\forall n \big(n \in \mathbb N \land n\geq 1 \implies f(n)=g(n)\big)$ can be proven both ways. However, I find that this seems to be a rare quality...or at least the ease with which one can find *both* methods seems to vary from proposition to proposition.

So my question is the following: If one can find success with a proof by induction argument for a given proposition, **must there exist** an "arbitrary element" argument for that same proposition? Similarly, if one can find success with an "arbitrary element" argument for a proposition, must there exist a proof by induction argument?

The two strategies seem fundamentally "different"...i.e. you could not assign each step a symbol in the arguments and form some sort of mapping strategy between each symbol to say that the arguments are actually the "same".

Thanks!

Comment: I will not write an answer, because I don’t consider myself experienced or educated enough. But I really like to take part in metamathematical discussions... I guess there is no correspondence between both methods and believe that if they are applicable at the same time it is mere coincidence. Proofs by induction require the problem to be ordered in some sense and rely on that order to show a universal statement. Arbitrary element proofs however seem to be the exact opposite, as they don’t require any knowledge of the structure of the problem whatsoever.

Comment: "arbitraty element" meand to prove that $P(n)$ holds for a natural number $n$ whatever (an unspecified one). Having done so, we are licensed to generalize on it, i.e. to assert that $P$ holds of **every** natural number, i.e. $\forall n P(n)$.

Comment: In the proof by induction, this is used in the induction step: "assume that $P(n)$ holds and prove that $P(n+1)$ holds", i.e. prove $P(n) \to P(n+1)$. Having done this, we generalize it o $\forall n (P(n) \to P(n+1))$.

Answer (score 2):

The "arbitrary element" proof here implicitly makes use of several theorems about the commutativity and associativity of finite series on $N$ that would require inductive proofs in a more formal mathematical setting.

Answer (score 1):

First, the 'arbitrary element' proof is better known as a *universal* proof.

And yes, if there is an inductive proof, then there is always a universal proof, and vice versa. It is just that there may not be a 'nice' or 'elegant' proof of the 'other' kind.

But yes, here is a trivial way to turn any univesl proof into an inductive proof (warning: it's going to be a 'groaner'!):

Simply define $P(n)$ to be the very claim $P$ that you are trying to prove, i.e. that you have already proven by the universal proof. Then the inductive proof is:

Base: First, we'll show that $P(0)$ is true. Well, $P(0)$ is just $P$, and we have a nice universal proof for $P$. Check!

Step: Assume that $P(n)$ is true. Well, $P(n)$ is simply $P$. But $P(n+1)$ is $P$ as well, and so we have shown $P(n+1)$. Check!

Ok, so now we have shown $\forall n P$. But since $P$ has no free variable $n$, that is simply the same as $P$, and so we are done.

Ok, so now let's (equally groanworthy!) transform any inductive proof of $P$ into a universal proof that $P$. Well, take any arbitrary number $n$. By the inductive proof, we can show $P$. Since $n$ was arbitrary, that means $\forall n P$. But since $P$ has no free variables $n$, that means $P$. Done.

Comment: lol. Groanworthy indeed! Cheers~